# Как не возвращать из метода значение?

Tags: macos, ios, xcode, objective-c

У меня есть метод, внутри которого в зависимости от разных условий я получаю объект или не получаю. Мне нужно указать в методе возращаемое значение. Как правильно указать это в названии метода, если могут быть оба случая - нормальный объект или nil?

Comment: Во-первых, гляньте мои исправления - хотя вопрос всё равно сформулирован немного не русским языком, но всё же стало получше. Во-вторых - когда вы возвращаете нормальный объект - он у вас какого типа?

Comment: объект типа NSmanagedobject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пишите ваш метод просто:

```
- (NSManagedObject *)yourMethodReturningNSManagedObjectOrNil {
    if (yourCondition) {
        NSManagedObject *yourManagedObject = ...
        return yourManagedObject;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Какие трудности у Вас возникают?

Comment: а разве return не должен быть последней строкой в методе?  и если я возвращаю nil из метода это нормально что тип значения на совпадает с тем что я указал в первой строке?

Comment: Ответ на первый вопрос - в С и производном от него Objective-C `return` может быть где угодно.

Comment: На второй - это нормально в случае, когда у вас возвращается Objective-C объект (типа NSObject, NSArray, NSManagedObject, ...).  nil - это нулевой Objective-C объект. Я не люблю такие вещи объяснять "официально" - читайте документацию и книги про это. Одно из объяснений для русских - http://habrahabr.ru/post/165021/, а вот для джентельменов - http://nshipster.com/nil/

Comment: Интересный стиль

    if (...) {
      ...
      return x;
    } else {
      return y;
    }

а так

    if (...) {
      ...
      return x;
    }
    return y;

чем-то не нравится?  IMHO короче и как-то прозрачней.

Comment: Вы пока что не путайте ТС, ему явно не об этом думать сейчас нужно)) Мне нужно было показать именно наличие выбора __или NSManagedObject__/__или nil__

Можно было бы ещё добавить, что, как правило, в Cocoa такой строки: `return nil` очень часто можно (и даже стоит) избежать в силу того, что очень многие методы в Cocoa (В Core Data в данном случае) возвращают nil сами и можно на них полагаться, но это совсем другая история.

Comment: Я бы вообще вот такое выбрал:

    X *x = nil;
    if (...) {
        // fill x
    }

    return x;

но тут уж каждому свое)

Comment: Тоже красиво.

Comment: Я обычно предпочитаю

    if (!...)
        return nil;
    ...
    return x;

Ранний return позволяет избавиться от ненужного scope'а.

Comment: Да ладно вам, количество и место точек выхода из функции это очень старый холивар, причем не на что особо не влияющий, хотя аргументы есть у обеих сторон. ТС явно не до него сейчас

ЗЫ Сам я за ранний ретерн в стиле VladD

Comment: @AlexDenisov, я это и имел в виду про "fill x" - тоже так поступаю во многих случаях (особенно с Core Data). @VladD, тоже абсолютно верно - "return early" concept. И да, @aknew, "ТС ясно не до него сейчас"...

P.S. Иногда кажется, что аудитория ХК (в объёме меток, на которые я подписан) состоит только из участников, отметившихся в этом топике ;). Шутка.